# How to delete the numbers in a copied list using notepad++

Tags: list, notepad++

I'm using notepad++ ; I copied a numbered list with text which looks like this

1. text
2. text
3. text
   .
   .
   .
4. text

I'd like to delete the numbers and leave just the text in each line...is there a quick way to do this in notepad++?

Comment: Are they at the start of each line? the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Ctrl+alt` also. Drag the numbers by holding Ctrl + Alt, then delete

Answer (score 0):

Press Shitf + Alt keys, then you will be able to select whatever part from text.

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad++ find/replace in regex mode:
`Find: \d+\. (.*)`
`Replace: $1`